# Responsive Design / Is it a good UX for a multi-step form?

Tags: usability, forms, web-app, responsive-design, user-expectation

I've got a responsive web app that displays a multi-step.
There are 4 steps: `What?`, `Where?`, `When?`, `With?`, that are indicated on each step to let user know the progress.

For instance, here's what it looks like in a desktop (the background is blue):

[image]

On a mobile device, it becomes like this:

[image]

I voluntary increase the padding of the buttons in order to fit all fingers.

In many native apps, the previous and next button are displayed on the top navbar.

The benefit of my layout is that it requires no touchy adaptation from desktop to mobile.

Is it acceptable? Or what could I improve to increase UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing buttons at the bottom are better as the thumbs or fingers could reach them easily - supports one hand operation too..

Comment: So like I did? No need to evolve the layout?

Comment: yes, Absolutely!

Comment: The only drawback I can see with my solution is that mobile's virtual keyboard may hide the buttons => user has to close it in order to click. In the contrary, when on top, user can clicks without needing to close the keyboard.

Comment: I don't see any text box..what launches a mobile keyboard here? Even so, the buttons must be co-located to the control that launches keyboard so that it will be visible. Also, hitting enter on keyboard should hide the board but I see it's not an ideal experience

Comment: In the screenshot, the textbox has the text: "24 New York ...". As soon as I typed "2", it launched the keyboard.

Comment: "Even so, the buttons must be co-located to the control that launches keyboard so that it will be visible." => on Iphone, the virtual keyboard isn't displayed under the input. Thus, if the input is not at the very top, it could be hide by the keyboard.

Comment: is the 'Next' button at the bottom complementary to the buttons at the top? if so, users would tend to click when? (in this context). Another idea is to put Previous and Next at the beginning and end of the button group (Previous, What?, Where?, When?, With?, Next)

Comment: Actually, What. When etc. are not buttons but @Balaji simply labels... I expect users to fill in the form in the order. Maybe should I represent them in another way to avoid confusion?

Comment: ok, How about horizontal progress line that you incrementally highlight every step of the way?

Comment: Why not :) Do you have some example of an horizontal line that would fit, without user trying to click on it?